# Версионирование, миграция схемы в Postgresql и CI

Tags: база-данных, git, postgresql, непрерывная-интеграция

Есть ли инструмент переноса схемы в гит с отслеживанием изменений? Что-то на подобии миграций django для голого sql?

Есть ли генератор миграций который может сделать переход из состояния A в B?

Не хочется искать руками десятки ALTER TABLE и DROP VIEW / CREATE VIEW в логе и создавать патчи вручную.

Comment: pgquarrel может? или sqitch?

Answer (score 1):

Для общего случая задача решения не имеет теоретического.

Простой пример, из

```
 create table foo (id serial, description text);
```

В

```
 create table foo (id serial, username varchar(50));
```

Возможно достичь как переименованием со сменой типа данных, так и удалением и добавлением колонки. Результаты на уровне данных при этом будут различны и именно разработчик должен решать, а что же здесь изменилось.

Посмотреть, что в принципе изменилось в базе, можно банально сняв дамп схемы данных `pg_dump -s` и посмотреть `diff`. Вполне рабочей идеей так же является ночной крон, который снимает дамп схемы с мастер-базы `production` и сохраняет его в `git`. Так остаётся история реальных изменений боевой базы.

Comment: Вот бы каждый объект в отдельный файл - тогда можно и дифы смотреть. А так то сложно все.

Comment: DDL/DML по описанию что то похожее

Answer (score 0):

pgCodeKeeper (http://pgcodekeeper.org/) - средство, облегчающее управление структурой данных и хранимыми процедурами на PL/PgSQL. На основе Eclipse. Cм также статью на Хабре (https://habr.com/post/276339/) и есть в telegram канал (t.me/pgcodekeeper)